# How to populate a grid using a DataTemplateSelector?

Tags: .net, wpf, datatemplate

I have a `Listview` that is populated with items I want the user to be able to edit. When the user clicks one of the items, the `Listview` slides to the side revealing a grid object meant to allow editing of the data associated with the `Listview` items. Each item in the `Listview` may be one of many types necessitating different controls to edit it, so I want the grid to be filled with the correct corresponding controls.

I tried to use an `ItemsControl` object with a `DataTemplateSelector` but the `SelectTemplate` function was not being called. I know I have the selector setup correctly because it's also being used to show the items in the `Listview` with their correct `DataTemplate`s.

The only solution I can come up with is to simply put every set of controls needed for the various types that may be present in the `Listview` and unhide the correct set when the `Listview` selection changes. I don't think this solution is very elegant, but I'm new to WPF and MVVM so I can't come up with a better one :-/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what is the mysterious "grid object" ...?  Is this your own control, or a DataGrid?

Comment: Apologies for the mystery. The grid object is a System.Windows.Controls.Grid. Basically a panel.

Comment: I think you should post relevant parts of your code.  It's hard to tell what's going on from just this description.